# Unity Animator: Animation is playing correctly in one layer and not playing in another

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Version of Unity: 2018.4.36f1
So here's the problem: I have a canvas and animations for Disclaimer game object. When animations located in Base Layer all works fine, but I need few animations playing in Canvas at one time, so I need layers. After I moved animation named Disclaimer to second layer, it's playing in animator (blue bar is fulling below name of animation), but isn't playing on screen. Here's all detailes and code, that works with animator:
[image: Base Layer]
[image: Second Layer]

```
    [SerializeField] private Animator canvasAnimator;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject loading;
    [SerializeField] private Animator disclaimerAnimator;
    [SerializeField] private Animator mainMenuAnimator;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject mainMenu;
    [SerializeField] private Text gameVersion;
    void Start()
    {
        loading.SetActive(false);
        disclaimerScreen.SetActive(true);
        canvasAnimator.Play(animDisclaimerShow.name,1);
    }

    public void HideDisclaimer()
    {
        disclaimerScreen.SetActive(true);
        mainMenu.SetActive(true);
        gameVersion.text = "Version:"+Application.version;
        canvasAnimator.Play(animDisclaimerHide.name,1);
    }
```

What I have tried?

- Changing layer types from Override to Additive
- Switching option in animator "Apply root motion"
- Setting weight to 1.0
- Applying option "Sync layers"
- Checking Static Batching (it's turned off)
  Nothing of this helped me, so I'm calling for your help. Thank you for any ideas or recommendations!